# Tagging files in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, tags, windows-explorer

Is there a way to enable file tagging in Windows 7 like it was possible with XP? I think all the file properties are handled by the file system, not the OS itself, so there must be some registry fix or shell extension to do this.

Comment: What sort of file tagging are you after that was available in XP but is missing from Win7?

Comment: I would probably want *anything else* that's around now instead of something that was available in XP.